# Load Pods-acknowledgements.markdown as NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I'm building an application and want to load the cocoapods auto-generated acknowledgements markdown file into an NSString to be displayed in my application. I though it would be as simple, as doing this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Pods-acknowledgements" ofType:@"markdown"];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

But this doesn't work.... Is there a way to access this file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't look like this file is automatically copied into your project bundle.

You need to add this file to your `Copy bundle Resource` build phase. It's also worth nothing that the file name actually contains your project's name `Pods-<PROJECT_NAME>-acknowledgements`

In practice you may want to make a symbolic link in your project that points to the generated file in the `Pods` directory to ensure that the newly generated file is used each time

[image]